# Where is better to do shaders, vfx, uv-mapping and coloring?

Tags: art, 3d-modeling

Well i understand that 3DS-Max is mainly for modeling and Unity is mainly for programming and logic, but where is it better to do shaders, vfx, uv-mapping/painting and coloring?

for example i worked a little bit in Blender and it has modifiers, but also Unity has materials and similar stuff.

What let's say "imade a model in 3ds max, now where should i do the art and texturing, should i continue with 3ds or should i do it in blender? OR it doesn't matter where?"

Answer (score 1):

Modelling, uv unwrapping, texturing, and skinning should all be done in your content generation tools (eg. 3DS Max, Blender, Photoshop, etc...)

Your final shader & material setup should generally be done in your game engine. Unless you're using a specific material creation tool that promises 1:1 consistency when imported into your engine, you'll usually find that the engine's rendering pipeline is substantially different than your source tools, and material settings/shaders will not translate between them exactly.

Unity's built-in tools for modelling/unwrapping/painting are basically limited to terrain, so sticking to what your source tools create here is usually your best bet. If you need to iterate on levels once they're assembled in Unity (eg. blocking out a placeholder asset, or blending models into their surroundings), custom tools & add-ons are available to help.